# Why is 'None' in builtins.__dict__

Tags: python, keyword, python-builtins

The following are true:

- `'None' in keyword.kwlist`
- `'None' in builtins.__dict__ # import builtins`

My understanding:

- Python evals identifier `x` by getting object `builtins.__dict__[x]`
- Python evals keyword `x` in a special way that depends on what `x` is

This implies that Python evals keyword `None` to the value of type `NoneType` (which is interned) without using `builtins.__dict__`. So why does `builtins.__dict__` contain `'None'`?

(the same question applies to `True` and `False`)

Comment: Good question! I suspect it's historical reasons, but I don't know that for fact. By the way, you can verify that the `builtins` version is never used by setting it to something absurd (like a string or a random number) and then accessing `None`. You'll still get the correct value of type `NoneType`.

Comment: `builtins__dict__` contains `None` because it's a name bound to a value in the built-in scope. Keywords are not, in general, evaluated *at all*; they are words which are reserved by the grammar and cannot be used as identifiers. (`None = 3` is a syntax error, for example, not just a runtime failure.)

Comment: In Python 2, you *could* redefine the value of `True` and `False`; they weren't actual literals, just pre-defined names bound to values of type `bool`. That was changed in Python 3, when they were made actual keywords.

Comment: @chepner I see your point about keywords not being evaluated in general. I suppose it makes some sense to talk about "evaluating" keyword literals (eg. None, True, False), but not other keywords (eg. if, for, etc.).  And your right that `None` is a name bound in the built-in scope, but the question is why is that the case, because that name has no obvious use.

Comment: [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) -- to be on-topic here a question should be expected to have a practical answer; that is, one that changes how you go about the _practice_ of software development. If something is a curiosity but has no impact on how you actually _use_ a language, it's not a practical question. We're not here to collect rants or complaints.

Comment: What do you mean, "has no obvious use"? It's a name, but is also like a literal. Historically, literals were the "atoms" that represented specific values, and `...` was the only one that was specifically enumerated, rather than defined via a regular expression. `None`, `True`, and `False` probably *could* have been defined as literals, but weren't for whatever reason, and `None` was the only one special-cased to be unassignable. (As metioned above, that was fixed in Python 3.)

Comment: @chepner but it is *not a name*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's a name for lookup purposes, though I will admit that it, `True`, and `False` are in their own region ("keywords with constant values") in the Euler diagram of parser-recognized strings.

Comment: @chepner it's not a name for lookup purposes, no name lookup is done when you use `None` in some expression. It doesn't seem like there are good docs as to what is supposed to be in `builtins` other than "‘built-in’ identifiers of Python" which for `None` I guess is somewhat true

Comment: @chepner @juanpa.arrivillaga btw, Silvio's first comment on this thread also demonstrates that no name lookup is done when you use `None` in an expression

Comment: @user615536 true, moreover, you can look at `import ast` and do `print(ast.dump(ast.parse("x = y")))` vs `print(ast.dump(ast.parse("x = None")))`

Comment: Frankly, I'm surprised you can write to `builtins._dict__` at all, or that it's even exposed as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Keywords, in general, aren't evaluated at all. The `keyword` module just provides, for informational purposes, which words are recognized as special by the Python grammar. In particular, `None`, `True`, and `False` are recognized as (hard) keywords so that attempts to redefine them are *syntax* errors, rather than runtime errors. Also, the list of keywords is not involved in name lookups at all.

Otherwise, `None` is just like any other name that is bound to some value (in this case, the lone value of type `types.NoneType`). In particular, the definition is in the built-in scope, so that it is available from any module without needing to import anything first. `builtins` just reflects those names that are defined in the built-in scope.

Comment: hmmm `None` is not a name. It is an atom.

Comment: You say "the definition .. is available from any module". Which is true in a way, but it seems that it is shadowed by the fact that `None` is a keyword. Perhaps this related question could be enlightening: is there any way to write a program that depends on the existence of `None` in `builtins.__dict__`?

Comment: @user615536 it is trivially possible to do that, e.g. `print(builtins.__dict__['None'])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good point! Of course my question was looking for a way that doesn't use that directly

Comment: OK, I see now, `None` is listed in the grammar (with `True` and `False`) as one of the expansions of the three different non-terminals. But semantically, I would still classify them as names because they form the unique intersection of "expressions" and "keywords". Conceptually, they are names mapped to values, even if any (all?) implementations can do the look-up at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: (`None` was not mentioned by the grammar at all in Python 2, so historically it was a speical-cased name, and maybe it is just an artifact of bygone days that `None` et al are still in the built-in scope.)

Comment: @chepner that sounds very plausible

Comment: It's a duck-typed keyword :) If it looks like a name, and evaluates like a name, ...